# Reveal p tag inside element with hover

Tags: jquery

I'm new to JS and am just trying to learn really specific, new functions outside of using CSS3. I want to learn how use hover to show an h1 element that's currently a hidden child within the div.

Here's my markup:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
  <h1>Project X</h1>
  <img src="img/concrete.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box h1 { display:none;
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".box").hover(function(){
        var ind = $(this).text();
        $("h1").text(ind)
    });
});
```

Comment: do you actually want to hide .box p or .box h1 in ur css?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? By doing this you are going to recursively increase the content in `.box` because `<h1>` is a child of it.

Comment: I just want to display the h1 within .box with hover, my CSS should be h1 not p

Comment: Javascript or jQuery is overkill if you want to display the `h1` tag on hover.  Pure CSS can accomplish this, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS doesn't make any sense... There is no `<p>` tag in your html code.

From what it sounds like this is what you need :
But, I am unsure as to whether or not you want to hide it when the user is no longer hovering over it.

### HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <h1>Project X</h1>
  <img src="img/concrete.png" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.box h1 { display: none}
```

### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".box").hover(function(){
        $('.h1').show();
    });
});
```

If you want to have it hide when the mouse is no longer hovering over the `div` you need to use the `mouseover` and `mouseout` functions

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".box").mouseover(function(){
        $('.h1').show();
    });
    $(".box").mouseout(function(){
        $('.h1').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: The OP asked for a js solution, but it should be noted that the same can be accomplished with only CSS.  See my answer below.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson if you refer to the tag and the syntax of his code it is JQuery. Although I do like your CSS solution a bit better

Answer (score 1):

You can change the properties of elements using `.css()`.  For example:

**The HTML**

```
<div class="box">
  <p>Here it is</p>  
  <h1>Project X</h1>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.box h1 { display:none; }
```

**The jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box").hover(function(){
    var ind = $(this).text();
    $(this).find("h1").css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/kXQXj/).

**This is overkill**

The same can be accomplished with pure CSS:

**The HTML**

```
<div class="box">
  <p>Here it is</p>  
  <h1>Project X</h1>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.box h1 { display:none; }
.box:hover > h1 { display:block; }
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/kXQXj/2/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use mouse enter and mouse leave events

```
$(".box").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('h1').show();
});

$(".box").mousleaver(function(){
    $(this).find('h1').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible way to do this is by setting a "state" CSS class on whatever you want to hide, in other words...

```
.hide { display: none; }
```

So for whatever paragraph you want to hide/reveal, start it like this:

```
<p class="hide">some text</p>
```

Then define two call backs, one to handle hover in and hover out like so:

```
$(".box").hover(function(){
    var $paragraphs = $("p");
    $paragraphs.removeClass("hide");
}, function() {
    var $paragraphs = $("p");
    $paragraphs.addClass("hide");
});
```

Check out my [simple fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/vE7m9/). Note that I recommend this method cause it can be easily extended to more objects by simply adding the `hide` class rather than making new CSS rules just to hide a specific element.

Hope this helps!